# Changing the height of a span element

Tags: html

I'm trying to implement a colored underline by putting the selected text in a span element and then giving the span a colored bottom border, like

```
border:bottom: 1px solid red;
```

This works, but the line is too far under the word:
[image]

Here's the border around the entire span element:
[image]

Does anyone see a way to reduce the height of the span element so the bottom border is closer to the word?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use height.

```css
span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
Does anyone see a way to <span>reduce</span> the height of the span element so the bottom border is closer to the word?
```

Comment: Thanks.  That worked but it doesn't really give me the colored underline I wanted. The actual height value needed is different for each font-size, to place the underline where it should go, and that opens up a can of worms.  So I'll just stick with the standard black underline, for now.

Comment: Change the height to line-height it make sense than height

Comment: Perfect!  `line-height' : currentFontSize`   works. That's the solution!  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Inline elements don't have a height, so you can change the display property to something like `inline-block`, and then use the `line-height` property to move the border closer:

```css
span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 10px;
}
```

```html
Does anyone see a way to <span>reduce</span> the height of the span element so the bottom border is closer to the word?
```